# How To Find Empty Spaces Vertically as well as horizontally in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to find empty spaces in the board which have 10 rows and 10 columns .
each row and column has 10 10 tiles .

my code is getting all the empty spaces in the horizontal way

```
   xoyo xoy1 xoy2 xoy3 xoy4 xoy5...
```

It is checking in the horizontal way now I want to check both in the vertical

```
    xoyo xoy1

    x1yo
```

**it should check in the horizontal and vertical direction in each iteration**

I have a board of 10 rows and 10 columns . I have initialize empty class to each box in the row and column.

```
   for($row=0;$row<10;$row++){
    for($column=0;$column<10;$column++){
        echo "<div xy='x".$row."_y".$column."' class='empty'></div>";
    }
}
```

I want to find empty space in the horizontal as well as vertical in the board.

```
foreach($collect as $col){

            echo "<p class='turn'>".$col."</p>";

    }
```

this is my horizontal function . which find the empty space horizontally in the board and place each combination.

```
 function get_position (){

        var count = 0;
        $(".turn").each(function(){
                count++;    
        });


        var randTurn = Math.round(Math.random()*count);


        var wordPick = "";
        $(".turn").each(function(i,e){
                if(randTurn == i)
                {
                    wordPick = $(this).text();
                }
        });
        var length = wordPick.length; 
        //alert(wordPick + " = " + length );
        for(var ver = 0 ; ver <= 9; ver++)
        {
            for(var hor = 0 ; hor <= (9-length); hor++)
            {           
                var got_it = false;
                var available_boxes = 0;
                var xy_pos = [];

                for(var word = 0 ; word < length ; word++)
                {
                    if($(".board div[xy='x"+ver+"_y"+(hor+word)+"']").hasClass("empty"))
                    {
                        available_boxes++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //alert(available_boxes + " = " + length);

                if(available_boxes == length)
                {

                        for(var word = 0 ; word <= length ; word++)
                        {
                            xy_pos[word] = "x"+ver+"_y"+(hor+word);
                        }

                        put_val(xy_pos,wordPick);

                        got_it = true;
                        break;

                }


            }

            if(got_it == true)
            break;

        }
      }
```

I want to find the empty space horizontally as well as vertical. it is doing in the horizontal way.

this get position functions iterates in this way.